# How tochange the text inside a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the text inside a link with jQuery when the href attribute is undefined.
 Here is my code;

```
<input type="text" id="sample"/><button id="button">submit</button>
<table id="table" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>less than 50</td>
     <td>less than 100</td>
     <td>less than 500</td>
     <td>less than 1000</td>
     <td>more than 1000</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

js:

```
$("#button").click(function()
   {
     var val=$("#sample").val();//alert(val)
       if(val<50){
           var col1=val; 
        }else if(val<100){
           var col2=val; 
        }else if(val<500){
           var col3=val; 
        }else if(val<1000){
           var col4=val; 
        }else if(val>1000){
           var col5=val; 
        }
          var row='<tr>'+
                  '<td><a href="#">'+col1+'</a></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#">'+col2+'</a></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#">'+col3+'</a></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#">'+col4+'</a></td>'+
                  '<td><a href="#">'+col5+'</a></td>'
                   $("#table tr:last").after(row);
                   $("#table").each(function(){
                      if ($(this).attr('href') == undefined){
                         var href=$(this).attr('href');                                         
                          $(href).text("");
                       } 
                   });
        }
      );
```

I need all undefined href text() to null or 0.I used like this.,

```
   $("#table").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == undefined){
            var href=$(this).attr('href');
             $(href).text("");
          } 
    });
```

But it doesn't worked.
Sql Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/2ok5mzx9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define them as `0`.

```
var col1 = 0;
col2 = 0;
col3 = 0;
col4 = 0;
col5 = 0;

if (val < 50) {
    col1 = val;
} else if (val < 100) {
    col2 = val;
} else if (val < 500) {
    col3 = val;
} else if (val < 1000) {
    col4 = val;
} else if (val > 1000) {
    col5 = val;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ok5mzx9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the `href` as `#`.

```
$("#table a").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == undefined || $(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        $(this).text("");
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2ok5mzx9/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change your script with this one:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    var range = new Array(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 50, 100, 500, 1000, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        if ($('#sample').val() > range[i + 1] || $('#sample').val() < range[i]) {
            continue;
        }

        $('#table tr:last td:eq(' + i + ')').html('<a href="#">' + $('#sample').val() + '</a>');

        break;
    }
});
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ok5mzx9/6/) is the working example..